# Why same python re pattern regex works in single line but not in multi line

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
regex =re.compile('''
((.*\n){2}
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.\n
(.*\n){1})
''', re.X)
```

Above code throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ''', re.X)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

while writing the regex in a single line works fine and there is no error

```
regex = re.compile('((.*\n){2}Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.\n(.*\n){1})')
```

Comment: Works fine on rextester https://rextester.com/QOAG9302

Comment: Python 2.7 is EOL, consider upgrading. It works fine on 3.4.4

Comment: I tried on Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. It works on both of them.